# how do I make a table that is creating itself from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table of the self creates tRestituiri is tImprumuturi

```
create table tImprumuturi
(
 ID_Imprumut int identity primary key,
 DataImprumut date default getdate(),
 DataScadenta as (dateadd(day,5,DataImprumut)) persisted,
 CodCD char(10) foreign key references tCD(CodCd)not null,
 CodCV char(10) foreign key references tCaseteVideo(CodCaseta),
 CodAb char(10) foreign key references tAbonati(CodAbonat) not null,
 CONSTRAINT ucCodCD UNIQUE (CodCD, CodCV), 
 CONSTRAINT ucCodCV UNIQUE (CodCD, CodAb), 
 CONSTRAINT ucCodAb UNIQUE (CodCV, CodAb)
 )
```

I want that tRestituiri to contain columns like:

```
tRestituiri
(
 ID_Restituire int identity primary key,
 DataRestituire // it should be equal with DataScadenta from tImprumuturi
 CodCD char(10) foreign key references tCD(CodCD),
 CodCV char(10) foreign key references tCaseteVido(CodCaseta),
 CodAb char(10) foreign key references tAbonati(CodAbonat)
)
```

BUT tRestituiri have to contain only values from tImprumuturi where DataScadenta is not older then current time {getdate()}-60 days** **I mean values from tImprumuturi where DataScadenta is not less than current time -2 months **

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you liked tables so I put a table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into tRestituiri (DataRestituire,CodCD , CodCV,CodAB)
SELECT DataScadenta,CodCD , CodCV,CodAB FROM tImprumuturi WHERE DataScadenta>GETDATE()-60
```